Gluing morphisms of schemes
Let $X$ and $Y$ be schemes and let $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ be an open cover of $X$. Suppose we are given scheme morphisms $f_i : U_i \to Y$ satisfying $f_i |_{U_i \cap U_j} = f_j|_{U_i \cap U_j}$ for all $i, j \in I$. Then there is a unique map of schemes  $f: X \to Y$ such that $f|_{U_i} = f_i$ for every $i \in I$.
On the level of topological spaces, define $f(x) := f_i(x)$ if $x \in U_i$. This is well-defined since if $x \in U_j$ then $x \in U_i \cap U_j$ and $f_i(x) = f_j(x)$. Moreover since each $f_i$ is continuous, $f$ is also continuous.
I am stuck at defining the sheaf map. I tried defining it for an open subset $V \subset Y$ I need to define a ring map $f^{\sharp} : O_Y(V)\to O_X(f^{-1}(V))$ in a compatible way. I do not understand how to make use of the condition $f_i|_{U_i \cap U_j} = f_j|_{U_i \cap U_j}$. Please help.

You've got a very good answer below, but I'm sure this can also be established more algebraically.  A sketch of what first came to mind: You can assume the $U_i$ are affine, which produces a commutative diagram of commutative ring homomorphisms, and then the result is effectively the universal property of the tensor product.

For a section $s\in O_Y(V)$ consider its pullbacks $f_i^\sharp(s)\in O_{U_i}(f_i^{-1}(V))=O_X(f^{-1}(V)\cap U_i)$. For any $i$ and $j$ the restrictions of $f_i^\sharp(s)$ and $f_j^\sharp(s)$ to $f^{-1}(V)\cap U_i\cap U_j$ agree, because they are equal to the pullback of $s$ by the morphism $f_i|_{U_i\cap U_j}= f_j|_{U_i\cap U_j}$. Therefore they can be glued to a section on the whole $f^{-1}(V)$.
And we have the compatibility with respect to inclusions $W\subset V$. We need to prove that the two sections of $O_X(f^{-1}(W))$ given by restricting $s$ to $W$ and then pulling back or pulling back first and then restricting agree. But if we restrict these sections to $f^{-1}(W\cap U_i) $, we obtain $f_i^\sharp(s|_W)$, therefore they agree by the sheaf axioms.
